# How do I serve swagger ui from my hapi-based server using swagger-ui-dist with an existing swagger.json?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, hapi

My project's vitals:

- TypeScript server-side web server project (not an SPA)
- Serves the ui & my api from the same server
- All api routes are served via path `/api/v2`
- Using [hapi](https://hapi.dev) for server
- Using [tsoa](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/) to generate *both* my hapi routes *and* my `swagger.json`
- My swagger spec contents at run time are available at `/swagger`

*NB: please don't point me to [hapi-swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-swagger) as I currently prefer the route generation of `tsoa`, which is incompatible with `hapi-swagger`.*

I would like to serve the swagger ui on my server at `/api-docs` so that it describes my `swagger.json`.

The [docs](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/) indicate that I should use [`swagger-ui-dist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist) to serve its contents statically by leveraging its `getAbsoluteFSPath()` method.  I'm happy to do that, but I just can't see how to configure `swagger-ui-dist` to use *my* swagger spec, available at `/swagger`.  The `index.html` at `node_modules/swagger-ui-dist` includes the following content:

```
  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
      })
      // End Swagger UI call region

      window.ui = ui
    }
  </script>
```

The aforementioned [docs](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/) say to serve directory `node_modules/swagger-ui-dist` statically, but they *don't* say how to configure the `SwaggerUIBundle`'s `url` to point to `/swagger` served from the same server that's serving that content.  I feel like copying the contents is not what you're supposed to do.

How do I serve the swagger ui from my server so that it displays the docs for *my* swagger and allows users of that ui to invoke the endpoints via the `Try it out` feature of swagger ui?